# Как сверстать такие уголки на чистом css, без использования svg?

Tags: html, css

Весь вопрос в заголовке. Я пробовал делать через border-radius, через псведоэлементы, но ничего не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Можно псевдами с использованием прозрачных границ

```css
*,*:before,*:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  background-color: #cda;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.car-body{
  margin: 10px 0 80px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:#555;
}
.car-body:before,
.car-body:after{
  content: '';
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
.car-body:before{
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #555;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
.car-body:after{
  top: 100%;
  border-top: 60px solid #555;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-body"></div>
```

Или подрезать используя `clip-path`

```css
*,*:before,*:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  background-color: #cda;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.car-body{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:#555;
  clip-path: polygon(10px 0, calc(100% - 10px) 0, 100% 10px, 100% 40px, calc(100% - 50px) 100%, 50px 100%, 0 40px, 0 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="car-body"></div>
```